# Cannot access to Apache Server on another folder

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, directory

I cannot access Apache server on another folder, this command I use

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/`

However, in the HTML folder I create another folder named Exe, and I use this `command sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/Exe/` when I start on my browser localhost/index.php it comes out error 404

**P.S** I can not rename or delete folder HTML or add folder in var directory.

Comment: Hi F.Živković, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question looks like it relates more to Apache than it does to Ubuntu, if you are indeed using Ubuntu please include what version, e.g. 18.04, 16.04 etc. in your question. Regardless you might get better help over at [Super User](https://superuser.com) so I would encourage you to post there.

Comment: Hi F.Živković! If the document root directory is set to `/var/www/html/`, you should be able to access the application/page inside the 'Exe' directory at `localhost/Exe`.